# How to install postgreSQL 10.15 version on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I want to install PostgreSQL 10.15 version on my ubuntu device,

referred below link and tried installing the same but it shows error:
https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-10.15
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-10.15'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-10.15'
```

for below command

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-10.15
```

or for below command

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql=10.15
```

i get below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '10.15' for 'postgresql' was not found
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: why install a version today that is end-of-live in 3 months?

Comment: I have to investigate an error we received with the usage of the flyway, and I am trying to recreate the same error in the local machine, hence need help to install PostgreSQL 10.15

Comment: The latest minor version for 10 is 10.22. The Postgres yum repositories do not keep old (unsupported) packages around. Just install 10.22  I would be **very** surprised if you can't reproduce a problem in your Flyway script with that version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Actually they do as the OP is looking for deb packages.  You need the [Archive repo](https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/). See [Postgres 10](https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-10/index.html)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: ah, greate didn't know that. I only use RedHat/CentOS based systems ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. PGDG RH repos also have [Unsupported packages](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages/#pgredhatoldrepos) .

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you

So I have to download the Debian file and install the same?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you

So I have to download the Debian file and install the same?

Comment: No you need to go here [Archives](https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/) and follow the instructions to set up the repo in `/etc/apt/`. Then you can run `apt install postgresql-10.15`

Comment: Actually it should be `sudo apt install postgresql-10=10.15-1.pgdg20.04+1`